# Certification Failed : Windows Phone"The application cannot be tested for compliance for Windows Phone Application Certification Requirements"

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I get certification failed for my windows phone 8 application.
My application is depend on the internet ( RSS feed)
Is the problem that I should add the "ID_CAP_NETWORK Capability) ? or  what ?

> Comments: The application cannot be tested for compliance for Windows Phone Application Certification Requirements due
>   to geographic, hardware, and/or software limitation(s). The application needs to access a web service to run properly, but
>   the web service is not functional.

Comment: Make sure that web service, that is used by your program works correctly. Or ensure the correct operation of the program if the web service is not working / no network, etc.

Comment: Yes as Lumen said, make sure to verify if no network exists that your app will throw an error. Use the "simulation dashboard" to simulate no network and poor network conditions.  Make sure you have ID_CAP_NETWORK selected, also as you stated.  This should help a bit. Handle no network errors gracefully and you should be OK.